# I want to compress the image

Tags: android, image

I am not familiar with Kotlin development. I want to compress the image. But don't know how I want to compress getImageFile into a png file. How do I compress using the compress method?

```
getImageFile.delete()
                    getImageFile.createNewFile()

                    val out = FileOutputStream(getImageFile)

                    contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri!!)?.copyTo(out)
```

This is the code that converts the image to a file. How do I do it here

```
src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, FileOutputStream(getImageFile))
```

I want to replace it using this method.But I get an error in src

Answer (score 0):

The main tasks are the following:

```
//open a stream
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
// Compress the bitmap with PNG format and quality e.g. 5% 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 5, stream)

//save it
val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
```

If it doesn't work you should check if your src is okay.
You can check out this tutorial -> [link](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/04/android-kotlin-compress-bitmap-example.html), it's the first I found on Google.